# divide client and server RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I have implemented a Java project (to create events,associate tasks on the events etc,) and all works correctly.

This is the project structure:

[image]

Now i want to divide this project into a Client and Server with RMI.
I use a DBManager class for performing all the query, so i use the objects of the other classes in the DBManager and also in the GUI!
Where i have to put the classes ( Event,Task,User,Admin ) in the client or in the server?

Some examples will be appreciated,thanks!

Comment: It is basically impossible to answer this question without seeing some code, or at least a complete class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

If you need classes that are shared between the client and server, you should make 3 eclipse projects.

First, a "core" project that contains the minimal set of shared classes, such as all your model object classes and utility functions.

Then, import that as a library dependency in eclipse for both a client and server project which contain their respective classes.

Otherwise, just identify which set of classes belong to the client vs server and make the appropriate eclipse projects for them.

The client and server projects will have their respective main method entrypoints that you can run individually. Only one server should be running, then multiple clients can be started simultaneously.

Comment: the problem is that i use the DBManager istance in all the shared classes! then i can't do what u are saying! :S

Comment: The DBManager goes in the core package, then

Comment: @Fr4ncx The problem is you can't do that. The client and server will run in different JVMs. Otherwise you don't need RMI at all. Surely the DBManager belongs in the server only?

Comment: and is correct to import the class that performes the query also in the client?

Comment: @Fr4ncx If the client has all this functionality what exactly do you think you need RMI for? What exactly is the server supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Fr4ncx So? This isn't making much sense. Normally the GUI will be in the client, and all the database stuff in the server.

Comment: I thought it was easy to implement RMI, at the end!

Comment: @Fr4ncx Easy to implement RMI *to do what?* This is the question, and you haven't answered it, even though you've been asked several times. Turning a monolithic project into a client-server project requires a purpose, thought, and re-architecting.

Comment: the track said to divide the client server! in order to have a centralized server and multiple clients!

Comment: Then identify which classes belong where and do that. It's highly unlikely you have circular dependencies in a client server architecture

Comment: @Fr4ncx I can't see your assignment. But you need to decide where the dividing line is. I've mentioned the usual structure. If adding a client/server division doesn't match the way your code is currently organised, you're going to have to change it. This is quite normal. A project that was originally built monolithically isn't just going to crack along some magical line like a diamond. It will take work.

Comment: and if i put the classes(event,task,user) in the client and also in the server ? obviously the DBManager in the  Server?

Comment: @Fr4ncx - "putting the classes" in both projects is exactly what the "core" project I mentioned does...